# How to save the file name with current date and time?

Tags: files, time, date, filename

I want to save the filename with current date and time by using a keyboard shortcut, is that possible?

Example:

```
array_12:35:16 28-05-16.php
somename_currentdatetime.php
```

[image]

Comment: which editor are you using ?

Comment: I'm using sublime.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: @AndroidDev. now see the update. i hope you understand it.

Comment: Do you mean rename in nautilus?

Comment: So want to able to save your currently open file in Sublime with a keyboard shortcut, and you want the saved file to have the date appended?

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes , that's it.

Comment: sure. how? please explain as answer.

Comment: Yahoo, we're a few days further, could you mention? As mentioned,  I'd like to wrap it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script below will allow you to right-click a file and choose the option <kbd>timestamp</kbd> from the <kbd>scripts</kbd> menu.

*right click -> Scripts -> timestamp*

[image]

*the file is timed*

[image]

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, safe it as `timestamp` (no extension) ìn `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`. Create the directory if it doesn't exist yet.
2. ***Make the script executable***. You might need to log out/in. Then the option should work.

The script inserts the time/date between the "body" of the name and the extension (any) if the extension is on the file. If not, it will add the time/date after the name.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import time

current = os.getenv(
    "NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
    ).replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ").strip()

t = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y")

name = current.split("/")[-1]; path = current[:current.rfind("/")]
splitmark = name.rfind(".")
newname = name[:splitmark]+"_"+t+name[splitmark:] if splitmark != -1 else\
          name+"_"+t
newfile = os.path.join(path, newname)
shutil.move(current, newfile)
```

#### Note

The script uses `python`'s `shutil.move()` which works equally on directories and files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40428/discussion-between-yahoo-and-jacob-vlijm).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide to creating plugins for sublime
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685

You can define a keybinding and attach it to command to generate your filename with a date in it. You might not be able to trigger the save but you can at least prefil the clipboard with the name and then paste it into the save box.